# How to do interpolation of captured variables in replacements in VSCode?

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, visual-studio-code, capture-group

If I want to replace something like

```
123-345
238-348
etc
```

with

```
xxx/123-345/yyy 
xxx/238-348/yyy
```

what I normally do in any editor is to search for something like

```
(\d{3}-\d{3})
```

and replace it with

```
xxx/$1/yyy
```

or

```
xxx/\1/yyy
```

(depending on the editor).

How do I do this in VS Code?

I have tried

```
xxx/$1/yyy
xxx/${1}/yyy
xxx/{$1}/yyy
xxx/`$1`/yyy
xxx/"$1"/yyy
"xxx/$1/yyy"
etc
```

None works. Well, some do the replacement but keep the delimiters ("..." or whatever).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `[0-9]` instead of `\d` i.e. `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})`?

Comment: I have tried again with version 1.36.1 and it works both with `[0-9]` and `\d`. I didn't add the version I had when I left this question, probably it has been fixed in the meanwhile. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in VS Code version 1.36.1.